# skip a subset of DejaGNU testsuite conditionally

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I am using DejaGNU to test a compiler toolchain.

I need to skip a bunch of execution tests - which try and run the compiled executable - but only when running those tests run on a particular emulator (QEMU). It is still relevant to run those executables on hardware so I don't want to simply remove the tests from the testsuite.

The [DejaGNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/dejagnu/manual/Customizing-DejaGnu.html) is pretty sparse on that topic. `man runtest` mentions a `--ignore` switch:

```
--ignore test1.exp test2.exp ...
        Do not run the specified tests.
```

I just cant work out which `.exp` i need to exclude from looking at the test results log. Does anyone know how to figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy.

First, the test log will tell which `.exp` failed. for instance:

```
Running ${NEWLIB_PATH}/testsuite/newlib.locale/UTF-8.exp ...
Executing on host: (bla bla bla)
PASS: newlib.locale/UTF-8.c compilation
spawn (bla bla bla)
Failed to set C-UTF-8 locale.
newlib.locale/UTF-8.c: Expected: Set C-UTF-8 locale. Got: Failed to set C-UTF-8 locale. 
FAIL: newlib.locale/UTF-8.c output
```

Notice the first line of this log entry says `Running UTF-8.exp ...`. Now, to skip it, simply run DejaGnu as follows:
`runtest --ignore UTF-8.exp`